# How can I set the relative path for all images in lyx?

Tags: graphics, lyx, paths

I have a huge file with hundreds of photos, all in one directory. For some reason, after sending the file to my friend, after he'd sent it back to me all the relative paths became different so I has to move the entire directory. I was wondering if there's a way to change the path for all photos at once? Also why did this change occur in the first place?

Comment: I don't know why it occurred in the first place. As for changing things back, in some cases it is useful to open a .lyx file in a text editor and do "find/replace". Although .lyx files have their own format, it is specified as plain-text and you can edit the paths.

Comment: Wise idea, I'll try it. It's very unclear how this happens

Comment: If you can reproduce the problem, please write up easy-to-follow steps to reproduce and open a ticket on https://www.lyx.org/trac. If there is a bug, we should fix it!

Comment: @scottkosty Trying to use find/replace works for the pictures but then for some reason all spaces between text and math boxes disappear!!

Comment: I'm surprised by that. After find/replace, did you check the diff to make sure nothing besides the paths was accidentally modified?